# Excel Datetime conversion from YYYYMMDDHHMMSS to DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

An auto generated report contains event times in the format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`.
How do I convert this to a more standard format `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter Excel formula solution exists: [Excel convert YYYYMMDDhhmmss [14-char text] to Date + Time (fastest way)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76876737/12246922)

Heres is my answer:

If you have this in the cell `D4` : `20161230055053` and you want this `12/30/2016 05:50:53`, then you need to use this formula

```
=DATE(LEFT(D4,4),MID(D4,5,2),MID(D4,7,2))+TIME(MID(D4,9,2),MID(D4,11,2),RIGHT(D4,2))
```

As you can see `D4` has the string with the data `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`, ans with that formula you can have a real formated date data where:

`DATE` is the formula that gives you the date using the parameters inside, `Year`, `month` and `day`.

And as any hour is the fraction of a day you can add the value of the hour, to the date using `TIME` with the parameters `Hour`, `Minute` and `Second`.

All the parameters that DATE and TIME use, is taking from de string `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` using the functions, `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `MID`.

Comment: I was able to custom format the resulting cell to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

```
=MID(#Ref!,7,2)&"/"&MID(#Ref!,5,2)&"/"&MID(#Ref!,1,4)&"  "&MID(#Ref!,1,2)&":"&MID(#Ref!,3,2)&":"&MID(#Ref!,5,2)
```

Where #Ref! is the cell with the original data

Long Answer:
Microsoft Excel defines MID function as a formula that “Returns the characters from the middle of a text string, given a starting position and length.” 
Syntax:
=MID( Input_string, Start_position, Number_of_characters )

Read more: [Excel Mid Funciton](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/excel-mid-function/)

Comment: You post a question and answer immediately... do you want a answer yet???

Comment: This answer gives you a String not a date time value, if you want to format or manipulate any how that result would be a mess, instead please see my answer.