# Excel convert YYYYMMDDhhmmss [14-char text] to Date + Time (fastest way)

Tags: excel, date, time, numbers, long-integer

Recently, I discovered a very quick way to convert `YYYYMMDD` [8-digit number starting with the year] to a date, via the "Text to Columns" conversion option in the data tab of MS Excel. It works like a charm:

[image: Text-to-Columns-conversion]

However, I couldn't do the same with a longer number, e.g. `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` [14-digit containing date + time]. The fastest option for conversion I found was through an additional column with the following formula:

```
=1*TEXT(@PrevColumn,"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00")
```

[image: Formula]

Does anyone know if a better conversion method exists (similar to the Text-to-Columns one above)?